# Thymeleaf th:with assignment of a local variable with a condition

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf into my templates.

I have this problem: I need to generate the `title` local variable using a condition.

```
<title th:with="title=(${firstName} == null and ${lastName} == null) ? 'TITLE A' : 'TITLE B'" th:remove="tag"></title>
<title th:text="${title}"></title>
```

using this code, into the resulted template, I obtain `<title></title>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thymeleaf understands scope.  So to fix this, you would want either have the `${title}` variable nested between the `<title>` tags or within the same tag:

```
<title th:with="title=(${firstName} == null and ${lastName} == null) ? 'TITLE A' : 'TITLE B'" th:text="${title}">[Title Here]</title>
```

Or

```
<title th:with="title=(${firstName} == null and ${lastName} == null) ? 'TITLE A' : 'TITLE B'">
       <span th:text="${title}" th:remove="tag">[Title Here]</span>
</title>
```

But, **your case can be simplified to:**

```
<title th:text="${firstName} == null and ${lastName} == null ? 'TITLE A' : 'TITLE B'">[Title Here]</title>
```

I would encourage you to keep some default text between the tags ("Title Here" in this case), so that a UI designer can view the page without having to run a container.